# TextformField validation message color Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

```
Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
                child: TextFormField(
                  autofocus: false,
                  obscureText: true,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    labelText: ' Confirm Password ',
                    labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    errorStyle:
                    TextStyle(color: Colors.red,                                // black26 if the background is white
                        fontSize: 15.0),
                  ),

                  // Controller for password
                  controller: confirmPasswordController,
                  validator: (value){
                    if(value == null || value.isEmpty){
                      return const Text(' Please confirm password ');
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                ),
              ),
```

I had the return value as: return 'Please Confirm Password ';

But I want to change the color of the font to white because my backgroundColor is black.

Can you guys help me?

Answer (score 0):

So if I’m getting your question correctly, you wanted to change the color of text returned by the textfield validator

For that, you can use the errorStyle properly of TextField

```
For this you have to use InputDecoration

TextFormField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    errorStyle: TextStyle(
      color: Colors.white
    ),
  ),
  ...
)
```

Comment: Yes I did. I did it already but thank you so much. This will help me and others in the future. Thank you!

Comment: You’re welcome! You can mark it as a answered (if it is correct answer)

Comment: Where I do that? I'm new to stackoverflow.